# How to check if a list has an empty string

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have a list `['', 'Tom', 'Jane', 'John', '0']`, and I wrote the following to check if it has empty string `''`:

```
if any('' in s for s in row[1:]):
        print "contains empty string, continue now"
        continue
```

I expect this to only pick the empty string, but this also picks a list that contains '0'. The '0' string is valid and I do not want to filter it out. So how can I check for an empty string in a python list?

Comment: `'' in s` -> `s == ''` (or more trivially `if '' in row`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just check if there is the element `''`  in the list:

```
if '' in lst:
     # ...

if '' in lst[:1]:  # for your example
     # ...
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> lst = ['John', '', 'Foo', '0']
>>> lst2 = ['John', 'Bar', '0']
>>> '' in lst
True
>>> '' in lst2
False
```

Answer (score 4):

```
any('' in s for s in row[1:])
```

checks, for each string `s` in the list `row[1:]`, whether the empty string is a substring of it. That's always true, trivially. What you mean is

```
any(s == '' for s in row[1:])
```

But this can be abbreviated to

```
'' in row[1:]
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using:

```
if any('' in s for s in row[1:]):
```

change your condition to:

```
if '' in your_list:
```

where *your_list* is name of list you are examining.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take your example and give the list a name:

```
list = ['', 'Tom', 'Jane', 'John', '0']
if '' in list:
    do something
```

That is all you need!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if any(len(x) == 0 for x in row):
    print("contains empty string, continue now")
    continue
```

Comment: This can give false positives if some elements of `row` are not strings.

Comment: I must add that my answer gives a false positive if `row` is a string, so whether that's enough of a problem to give a downvote is questionable.